# How to use the fingerprinting feature to optimize your privacy with firefox

Tags: firefox, javascript, html5, tracking, private-browsing

Superusers, I know by now how the new firefox fingerprinter works and what it does thanks to another question. But this question now is: to understand this setting's impact on the actual user-tracking efforts.

Is it better to activate this new fingerprinter setting, or not - when you like to be "less" easier trackable/traceable during web surfing (across many days)?

Because I have read differing things. There are those who say if you block fingerprinting in firefox you will look more "unique" and thus better tracable, and those who say, If you allow fingerprinting, your canvas hash (fingerprint) may be "less unique" and thus not easy to track in the masses of users...

Can you explain what makes technically more sense for reducing tracability efforts?

(By tracability, I mean for example: knowing that a user that visited the website today youtube.com, is the same user that visited after 7 days the website twitter.com)

Answer (score 1):

The techniques you're describing fall into two main categories...

1. Blocking scripts from tracking sites entirely, and
2. Reducing uniqueness entropy by spoofing user-agent and system info.

Obviously, option 1 is the best because if those scripts can't load, they can't possibly fingerprint you. That's what most addons, and Firefox's built-in tracker protection do: they operate off a blacklist of domains that are known to track you. The website you're using can detect if you block those trackers (by side-effects, such as global variables not being set) and then use that to trigger a rule (like showing anti-adblocker messages) but in general, it's not going to do much to identify you uniquely.

Category 2 is the more difficult one. Firefox does make an effort to hide and spoof certain details about your browser and system, such as masking the plugins list so they can't be enumerated, rounding screen resolutions to the nearest 100px, reducing the precision of timers to the nearest 100ms, and many more. This [gHacks article](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/01/a-history-of-fingerprinting-protection-in-firefox/) and [this Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Fingerprinting) list even more, and when they were introduced.

That being said, there are certain APIs and pieces of info that are considered *too useful to break*, as Mozilla puts it. These include browser's major version, operating system, time zone, and locale. If you want to reduce your entropy further, you could install addons that spoof these things to 'blend in' better. For example, if you're running Linux and live in Germany, then spoofing as Windows 10 and saying your locale is English (US) will reduce your entropy greatly.